# RequireJS doesn't work on a multipage project with CDN hosted libraries (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, requirejs, bundling-and-minification

I'm using RequireJS on a multipage project, with a Javascript folder structure that looks kinda like this (how do you make those fancy dir trees again in Markdown?):

```
common.js
lib/
-- jquery-1.9.1.min.js
-- modernizr-2.6.2.min.js
-- underscore-amd.min.js
page/
-- index.js
-- start.js
-- checkout.js
```

Anyway, `common.js` is my main script file that is where I set up the configuration parameters. This is what that looks like:

**common.js file**

```
// Configure RequireJS
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "assets/js/lib",
    paths: {
        page: '../page',
        jquery: [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min',
            //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
            'jquery-1.9.1.min'
        ],
        modernizr: [
            '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min',
            //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
            'modernizr-2.6.2.min'
        ],
        underscore: [
            'underscore-amd.min'
        ]
    }
});
```

All the page calls work as expected (with the CDN location being loaded), but I can't get my head around the minification part. The `r.js` optimizer simply refuses to cooperate, throwing an `Error: paths fallback not supported in optimizer. Please provide a build config path override for underscore` even though Underscore doesn't have a CDN specified.

**build.js file**

```
{
    appDir: '../www',
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    dir: '../www-built',
    mainConfigFile: '../www/assets/js/common.js',
    modules: [
        //First set up the common build layer.
        {
            //module names are relative to baseUrl
            name: '../common',
            include: ['jquery',
                      'modernizr',
                      'underscore'
            ]
        },
        // Now the page scripts
        {
            //module names are relative to baseUrl/paths config
            name: '../page-index',
            include: ['page/index'],
            exclude: ['../common']
        },
    ],
    paths: {
        jquery: "empty",
        modernizr: "empty"
    },
    optimize: "uglify2",
    removeCombined: true
}
```

Please help me figure out how to build this project to create the `common.js` script along with the individual page scripts.

(Note: I based the structure of my `build.js` file on [this example](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage)

### Updated!

I've updated the question to include the correct syntax for `empty:` (thanks Travis!), and now the build runs without error. However, my JS files are not concatenated or uglified. The CSS files are, at the import points, so something's happening. Complete `build.js` file below (forgive me, but she's a tall one):

```
{
    appDir: '../www',
    baseUrl: 'assets/js', // relative to appDir
    dir: '../www-built',
    mainConfigFile: '../www/assets/js/common.js',
    modules: [
        //First set up the common build layer.
        {
            //module names are relative to baseUrl
            name: 'common',
            //List common dependencies here. Only need to list
            //top level dependencies, "include" will find
            //nested dependencies.
            include: ['jquery',
                      'modernizr',
                      'underscore',
                      'bootstrap'
            ]
        },

        //Now set up a build layer for each page, but exclude
        //the common one. "exclude" will exclude nested
        //the nested, built dependencies from "common". Any
        //"exclude" that includes built modules should be
        //listed before the build layer that wants to exclude it.
        //"include" the appropriate "app/main*" module since by default
        //it will not get added to the build since it is loaded by a nested
        //require in the page*.js files.
        {
            //module names are relative to baseUrl/paths config
            name: 'pages/home',
            include: ['pages/home'],
            exclude: ['common']
        },
        {
            //module names are relative to baseUrl/paths config
            name: 'pages/start',
            include: ['pages/start'],
            exclude: ['common']
        },
        {
            //module names are relative to baseUrl/paths config
            name: 'pages/checkout',
            include: ['pages/checkout'],
            exclude: ['common']
        },
    ],
    paths: {
        jquery: "empty:",
        modernizr: "empty:"
//        underscore: "empty:"
    },
    optimize: "uglify2",
    optimizeCss: "standard",
    removeCombined: true,
    preserveLicenseComments: false
}
```

### Final Update (Yaay! It's working)

Thanks to Travis below, everything is working great! (the files are getting minified and concatenated). Since his solution is hosted on Dropbox, and could be lost in the future (who knows amirite?), I'll just sum up the fixes he made:

#### 1. Don't mix `define` and `require` calls in a single file.

I had a couple of files where I'd mixed them like so:

**page/start.js**

```
 define(['jquery','underscore'],function($,_) {
      ...
 });

 require(['jquery','page/start'], function($, Y) { // BAD!
      ...
 });
```

and the fix was to do this:

**page/start.js**

```
 require(['jquery','app/start_helper'], function($, Y) {
      ...
 });
```

**app/start_helper.js**

```
 define(['jquery','underscore'],function($,_) {
      ...
 });
```

#### 2. It's `"empty:"` not `"empty"`

That's a tricky one, though the RequireJS docs mention them.

#### 3. Because

what kind of list has just 2 bullet points?

---

Awesomelicious - now it works like a charm :)

Comment: Anyone? It's quiet over here :(

Comment: Have you tried adding a CDN for underscore? There's one here: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js

Comment: @skishore problem there is that it isn't wrapped (you can't use a non-AMD module like Underscore as is in RequireJS without wrapping it in a `define` call)

Comment: Could you please add _"Don't mix `define` and `require` calls in a single file."_ as a separate answer and choose it as solution?

Comment: @kaiser there were several issues with my code, one of which was the mixing of the `define` and `require` calls. I've edited Travis's answer to highlight that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like requireJs thinks that you're trying to provide a paths fallback for underscore, since you're specifying its path value as an array. Try just doing it as a string instead.

```
paths: {
    underscore: 'underscore-amd.min'
}
```

Also note that the [correct symbol for empty paths](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty) is `empty:` (with a ':') not `empty`.

Finally, as an unrelated side note you could always look at [lodash](http://lodash.com/) which is IMHO a more customizable, cross-browser compliant, faster underscore replacement with an identical API and it's hosted on cdnjs and is AMD-compliant

**UPDATE**

Following up on the conversation within the comments, here's my updated version of your project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21823728/so_rjs.tar.gz

As mentioned in the comments, your problem seemed to be that you were `define`ing modules within the same file that you were requiring those modules in, and that I believe was causing r.js to believe that these modules had no main entry point. The convention is to separate out module definitions from files that require those modules.

Notice there's an `app` folder now under `assets/js` where each module that used to be `define`d within your page modules is now stored. Your page modules now `require` these modules in. When I re-ran `r.js` (using uglify2 as the optimizer) everything seemed to work as expected.

Furthermore, I removed some redundancy from your build.js file (you only have to specify baseUrl in your mainConfigFile if that's the one you're using for your build configuration as well). Finally, you may want to look into using the [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) if you want to attach jQuery and Bootstrap globally to every page. Otherwise you should just explicitly list them as dependencies when you need them.

Finally as one last piece of advice you may want to look at cutting down on the number of `require` within each file. For most of those pages you could wrap everything in one require call and then just separate out different logic into functions to save some space on the event queue and also some cycles of having to redundantly call the `require` function.

Comment: You're absolutely right! It's `empty:` with an `:`! I feel so stupid right now. I ran the `node r.js -o build.js` command and it completes without error. The only problem is that none of the JS files are minified or concatenated. (The CSS files however are concatenated at the `@import` points, so it is doing *something*). Any ideas? - I've posted the complete `build.js` in the question

Comment: Glad I could help! re javascript not being concatenated optimized: what version of requireJs are you using? "uglify2" is only available after 2.1.2. Plus if you let me know your version then I can try and replicate your issue. Also, is there a reason why you're using `removeCombined`? According to the [example build script](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) if this is set to true then "any files that were combined into a build bundle will be removed from the output folder," which I don't think sounds like the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: (continued from last comment) Try changing the `optimize` value to "uglify" instead of "uglify2" and getting rid of the `removeCombined` line and see if that helps! Otherwise let me know what version of requirejs you're using and I'll try to replicate the problem.

Comment: Thanks Travis! Tried your suggestion (removed `removeCombined` and switched to `uglify`) and still no luck. I'm using the latest version of RequireJS, so that's `2.1.8`. 

Also, I've uploaded my entire folder structure [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rf7nj2k8ry7jwkv/xlt2IJnvot/tmp) for your reference. Thanks!!

Comment: The build command I use (in the root `/` folder) is: `node tools/r.js -o tools/build.js`

Comment: Your issue was that you were `define`ing modules within your top-level page modules, i.e. mixing `require` and `define` calls. `r.js` seems to expect that in your top-level page modules you only use `require` calls and any `define`d modules should be placed in separate files (one per file).

Comment: see my updated answer for a solution that seemed to work for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, the "Looks like requireJs thinks that you're trying to provide a paths fallback for underscore, since you're specifying its path value as an array." saved me. The error message is not very clear.